# Where should put RewriteCond and RewriteRule?

Tags: apache-2.2

I am using Apache as the HTTP server in order for me to access the Subversion repository, since I don't find any `.htaccess` file as I am not tied the svn directory to `/var/www`, can I put the `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` in `httpd.conf`?

Comment: Yes. See http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) provides a fairly standard block of information for every Apache directive.

[`RewriteCond Directive`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

```
Description:  Defines a condition under which rewriting will take place
Syntax:       RewriteCond TestString CondPattern
Context:      server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess
Override:     FileInfo
Status:       Extension
Module:       mod_rewrite
```

Note the [`Context:`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/directive-dict.html#Context)

This tells you where a particular directive may be used.

Comment: @lain Thank you so much on your guidance, I have overlook the doc.

Answer (score 1):

Putting these in `httpd.conf` (in your virtual host section for the repositories) is certainly possible.  Additionally, if you are including the virtual host by reference to another configuration file, you should put the mod_rewrite directives in there.

I actually find it preferable to do this; `.htaccess` files should be disabled whenever possible.  This is particularly true on sites to which users can upload content, to minimize security exposure and keep configuration completely out of band.  It also has performance implications -- the `.htaccess` file is reread every time a URL to which it might apply is accessed, because it can change without a configuration reload, whereas the actual server configuration is only reevaluated when rehashing or starting apache.

Comment: Using .htaccess files may also cause a reduction in performance, since the server will re-read the .htaccess file on every access. The main config file will only be re-read when the server is started or a reload command is issued.

Comment: Good point; I never thought of that.  I'll edit it in.

Comment: Most sites won't notice the difference, but I've been in places where it's been *very* noticeable.